# "units of measure" vs "units of measurement"

Tags: phrase-usage, writing, terminology

I sense that there is a subtle difference between *units of measure* and *units of measurement*.

I'm writing an English application manual and now arrived at a chapter about units by which users can choose to enter or display their data (hectares, miles, meters, etc.). Which of the two phrases should I use?

Comment: I answered your question in more general terms but, in your particular situation, I would use specific terms such as "unit of area" and "unit of length,"  whenever possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term **unit of measure** is commonly used
as well as universally understood and accepted
in medicine, other sciences, and engineering — leaving
no need to use the longer term, *unit of measurement*.

In this usage, *measure* and *measurement* are essentially identical:

> **measure**   2.1   A system or scale of standard measuring units
>   – [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/measure#measure__24)
>
> **measurement**   1.2   A unit or system of measuring
>   – [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/measurement#measurement__6)

If this reduces to a survey of opinion, mine is that the broader meaning
of *measurement* unnecessarily evokes the act that produced the result;
the act itself should receive sufficient attention in the surrounding text.

If the amounts in question are input parameters rather than reports of
actual measurements, the term *unit of measure* is more
appropriate than *unit of measurement*.

More about *measurement* can be seen at
[English Language & Usage: Difference between “measurement” and “measuring.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52567)

Even though the writers of Wikipedia's article chose *Units of measurement*
as its title,
[Wikipedia also says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_of_measure_%28disambiguation%29):

> **Unit of measure** commonly refers to
>   [Units of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_measurement)
>   for relevance to weights and measures.